# How to stop slide from showing all slides vertically when loading

Tags: slider, slick.js

My logo slider shows every slide vertically when loading and it looks terrible when loading and then when loaded it forms correctly.

Can someone please let me know how to get rid of this problem please? Here's where the slider is located http://www.customlogoshop.com/logo-design

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to hide the images like this:

```
.logo-slider img {
    display: none;
}
```

and make them visible again as soon as slickjs initialized the slider:

```
.logo-slider.slick-initialized img {
    display: block;
}
```